# backbone.js remove item from series

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am currently learning backbone.js and am wondering about removing an item from a series. I am working on the infamous recipe app and am creating step by step directions within textareas. I want to be able to remove one textarea without removing all of them. the creation event is like this:

```
"click #btnAddDirection": "addNewDirection"

         addNewDirection: function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            this.directionCount++;
            this.render(this.directionCount);
        },
```

and my remove looks like this:

```
'click .subDirection': 'subDirection'
        subDirection: function () {
            this.$el.remove();
        }
```

the issue I have is that when I click the [-] button all of the directions are removed rather than a single one. I am thinking I need to pass some sort of identifier in for the direction. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

here is the entire Direction Control View:

```
        // The Direction Control View
    var DirectionControl = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function (directionCount) {
            if (directionCount == null) {
                directionCount = 1;
            }
            var that = this;
            var directions = new Directions();

            var completeDirections = _.invoke(directions, 'fetch');

            $.when.apply($, completeDirections).done(function () {
                var template = _.template($('#direction-control-template').html(), { directions: directions.models, directionCount: directionCount });

                $('.tblDirections').each(function () {
                    $(this).find('.addDirection').remove();
                    $(this).find('.newDirection').text('');
                });
                $(that.$el).append(template);
            });
        },

        events: {
            "click #btnAddDirection": "addNewDirection",
            'click .subDirection': 'subDirection'
        },

        directionCount: 1,

        addNewDirection: function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            this.directionCount++;
            this.render(this.directionCount);
        },

        subDirection: function () {
            this.$el.remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Without seeing your markup and views it's a little hard to pinpoint exactly but it sounds like your click event is matching all of your textareas, do they all have the same class (*subDirection*)?

Comment: yes. I was wondering about adding directionCount to each area to differentiate. Just wasn't sure exactly how or where.

Comment: Your `$el` is the root element of your entire view, so when you remove that you are removing everything within your view. In this case what you want to do is use the passed in event to get the element that fired the event. For example something like `subDirection: function (e) { $(e.currentTarget).remove(); }`.

Comment: Alternatively you can have a separate view for each direction.

Answer (score 0):

A Backbone best practice in this type of situation would be to give each direction its own individual View. Then, if you create an event within the Direction view, it will only trigger on elements within that view.

On your callback after the directions are fetched, you could try to loop through each in `directions` and create a new DirectionView view:

```
DirectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {/*put click events for the individual direction here*/}
    render: function(){/*render to this.el */ return this}
})
```

after you create the new DirectionView, you can render it to the main view you already have:

```
$(that.$el).append(directionView.render().el);
```

Comment: thanks much. Think I will go back and see if I can implement this first.

Answer (score 0):

Your `subDirection` function will receive an `event` object in its parameters- you can use this to remove the correct direction. I suggest adding an `id` for each direction, but if you aren't worried about duplicates you could just pretend the content of the direction is the `id`.  Example:

```
subDirection: function(event){
  var $direction = $( event.currentTarget ).siblings('.direction-container');
  var directionId = $direction.text();

  // loop through the model's directions until you find the corresponding direction
  // then remove that from the directions array

  this.render(); // re-render the view
}
```

This is more of a jQuery-esque solution - not the Backbone best-practice like @Kyle R's, but this will accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

what ended up working was to add data-index to the item in this fashion.

```
   <!--Table for Direction entry control -->
<script type="text/template" id="direction-control-template">

    <table class="tblDirections" id="idx_<%= directionCount %>">
        <tr>

            <td class="Directionlabel">Step # <%= directionCount %><input type="hidden" name="DirectionStep" value="1" />:</td>
            <td class="Direction"><textarea id="Direction" rows="5" cols="70"></textarea><br></td>
            <td>
                    <button type="button" id="btnAddDirection" class="btn btn-success btn-xs addDirection">+</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubDirection" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs subDirection" data-index="idx_<%= directionCount %>">-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

the control looks like this:

```
           subDirection: function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var currentTarget = $(ev.currentTarget);
            var idx = currentTarget.data("index");
            console.log("got index of " + idx);
            $("#" + idx).remove();
```